# Sqlalchemy filter query

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Hello I have a little Flask application that I am trying to develop.

I have a Boat class and it has boat_name and length that I query.

```
Boat.query.filter_by(numberofcabins=numberofcabins)
```

query works and I get what I look for.

But

```
db.session.query(Boat).filter_by(length = length)
```

or

```
Boat.query.filter_by(length=length)
```

query does not get any result.

I don't know what is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
Boat.query.filter_by(length=length)
```

requires an `.all()` appended to the end.

```
>>> type(Boatquery.filter_by(length=length))
<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>
>>> type(Boatquery.filter_by(length=length).all())
<type 'list'>
```

[Documentation for `.all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all)
[Documentation for `.filter_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by)

Comment: Thank you Celeo I tried .all() now did not work :( by the way length is type float does it matter

Comment: You'll want to insure that there are actually matching records in your database. Use the appropriate command-line client to get into the database and run the SQL query manually.

Comment: I checked as you said SELECT * FROM boats
WHERE length=15; This query found what I looked for

Comment: If your local `length` is a float, and the model field is an `int`,  then try performing a cast on `length` before calling the `filter_by`

Comment: Sorry I found my error it was a !=None issue I changed it to !='' now it works. Thank you Celeo for spending time